# pd.read_csv has issues with differing number of columns between csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have number of csv files that have differing numbers of columns.
Majority of the csv files are 4 columns wide and gets read and concatenated.
 
However, when it encounters files that exceeds 4 columns the script errors out.

I get the following error message:
`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 125, saw 8.`

If I refactor the code (below) to include `error_bad_lines=False` for the `pd.read_csv`,
the code completes and outputs a combined csv that includes only the lines that contain 4 columns.

How can I solve this error, and concatenate everything?
There're no indexes, so i'd just have to stack the csv info on top of one another.

Thank you so much

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


all_filenames = [
   # think this is working correctly with bunch of replies.csv extensions
   i for i in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\tkim1\\Python Scripts\\output\\*\\replies.csv')
] 

print(all_filenames)

# combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([
   pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=False) for f in all_filenames
], sort=False)

# export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_replies.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with pandas.concat, not pandas.read_csv. The concat function does not allow you to concatenate DataFrame objects with differing number of columns.

The only way I can think of solving this is to find out the DataFrames that have lesser number of columns (than the DataFrame with max number of columns), set the required extra columns in each DataFrame to NaN, then apply pd.concat.

```
# for example, if df1 has 3 columns and df2 has 2 columns, set the third column in df2 
# to NaN, then apply concat.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0': np.arange(1, 100), 
                    '1': np.arange(100, 1, -1)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0': np.arange(100, 200), 
                    '1': np.arange(200, 100, -1), 
                    '2': np.arange(400, 500)})
df2['2'] = np.nan
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: just tried your code. I am able to concatenate without adding np.nan by using index= False. Was already incorporated